# How to deal with the SIGNAL(with arguments) of dynamically added QObject in QT?

Tags: c++, qt, signals, signals-slots

I've found out that `QSignalMapper` can deal with the `SIGNAL`s with **NO Arguments**, but how can I deal with some `SIGNAL`s with it's arguments.

The actually problem is, I have created some `QProgressBar` dynamically, and i wanted to use `QNetworkReply`'s `downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)` to update the bar, then the problem occurred.

Comment: Why do you want to use `QSignalMapper`?

Comment: @Lol4t0 Nonono..I just found it by google, and i do not have to use it, and it seems can't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `QNetworkReply's downloadProgress(qint64, qint64)` and `QProgressBar`'s slots are incompatable in any way. And signal mapper will not help you in this case, that is too specific.

You have to make you own adapter class:

```
class Adapter: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Adapter(QProgressBar* bar, const QNetworkReply* reply):QObject(bar)
    {
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(downloadProgress(qint64,qint64)), SLOT(changeProgress(qint64,qint64)));
    }

private slots:
    void changeProgress(qint64 progress, qint64 total)
    {
        QProgressBar* bar = static_cast<QProgressBar*>(parent());
        bar->setMaximum(total);
        bar->setValue(progress);
    }

};
```